# flat resolutions of almost modules?

Tags: homological-algebra, perfectoid-spaces

Recall the set-up in 2.4.10 of [Almost Ring Theory by Ofer Gabber and Lorenzo Ramero](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0201175.pdf):

- $V$ is a commutative unital ring.
- $\newcommand{\gm}{{\mathfrak m}}\gm$ is an ideal in $V$ such that $\gm^2 = \gm$.
- $A$ is an almost $V$-algebra (in the sense of 2.2.5).
- $M$ is an $A$-module.

The example relevant to my question is when $V$ is the ring of integers of the $p$-adic completion of $\Bbb Q_p\!\left(p^{1/p^\infty}\right)$, and $\gm$ is the maximal ideal. Note that it is generated by $\{x_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$ where $x_n := p^{1/p^n}$. We also let $A = V^a$.

By 2.4.5, the only projective $A$-module is $0$, but we do have enough almost projective $A$-modules, in the sense of 2.4.4, by 2.4.8. Note that every almost projective $A$-module is flat by 2.4.12, so $A$-modules also have enough flat objects. (Tensor product is defined in 2.2.5.)

My question: **The authors claim, in 2.4.10, that the functor $M \otimes_A -$ can be derived by taking flat resolutions, but I am having trouble seeing why the Tor functor so constructed is independent of the resolution**.

Clearly it is sufficient to show that any two almost projective resolutions of an $A$-module are chain homotopic, but I cannot show even that. The classical argument in [Weibel](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/an-introduction-to-homological-algebra/AAA3F16482097015CD12D4376D505282) 2.4.1 proves this using the "Comparison Theorem" 2.2.6, which says that given projective resolutions $P_\bullet \to M$ and $Q_\bullet \to N$ and a map $f: M \to N$, there is a chain map $P_\bullet \to Q_\bullet$ that lifts $f$, and the chain map is unique up to chain homotopy.

However, I am having trouble translating this argument in the setting of almost projective resolutions. In particular, I cannot even show that there is a chain map $P_\bullet \to Q_\bullet$ lifting $f$. Indeed, the fact that $P_0$ is almost projective only tells us that $\newcommand{\alHom}{\operatorname{alHom}}\alHom(P_0, Q_0) \to \alHom(P_0, M) \to 0$, i.e. any map $P_0 \to M$, **when multiplied by any $\varepsilon \in \gm$**, can be lifted to a map $P_0 \to Q_0$. This does not produce a map $P_0 \to Q_0$ that lifts the given map $P_0 \to M$.

In our example, let $M = A$, $P_0 = A$, and $Q_0 = A^{\oplus \Bbb N}$. Also let the map $Q_0 \to M$ (be induced by the map that) sends $\sum a_n e_n$ to $\sum a_n p^{1/p^n}$. Then it can be verified that there is no map $P_0 \to Q_0$ lifting the identity map $M \to M$.

**I know that if the Tor functor exists then it can be computed using flat resolutions, so my question is about the existence of this Tor functor to begin with**.

Comment: Note that there are more general ways than projective resolutions to show existence of derived functors. See for example [Tag 05S7](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05S7), which you would apply to $\mathcal D$ the homotopy category of chain complexes of your favourite abelian category, and $S$ the multiplicative system of quasi-isomorphisms; see [Tag 05T3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05T3).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Does it make sense to use [Tag 06XN](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06XN) with $\mathcal{I}$ being the (classes of) chain complexes with free terms?